# php set header expires date not working

Tags: php, caching

I have a simple **php** script running on **localhost** that sets expire date like the following:

```
// current date is **Tue, 17 Sep 2013**
header(
        'Expires: Sat, 22 Sep 2013 03:53:08 GMT');
}

echo "Original content";
echo ( '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">View Again</a><br />' );

// echo "Content changed still visible though I set expire date already!";
```

After saving this and load the content the first time, I remove the second comment which prints out the a new line and hit the *View Again* button. But instead showing the first cached content (which only has one line "Original content"), it still displays the added second line.

Am I misunderstanding something or what goes wrong with this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `Cache-Control: public` before `Expires: ...` header:

```
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 22 Sep 2013 03:53:08 GMT');

echo "Original content: " . date('d.m.Y H:i:s');
echo '<a href="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '">View Again</a>';
```

---

**UPDv1:**

Another option is to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` by `isset()`. If it exists, then parse it and compare with expiration date. If it lesser, then force script to return HTTP 304 as response header:

```
header('Last-Modified: ' . /* expiration date there -> */ gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT', true, 304);
```

It will force browser to use cached copy of loaded page.

Comment: @CORRUPT, Though it works for 'View Again' button, it doesn't work when I refresh the page. Could you review your answer again? Thank you.

Comment: @CORRUPT after reviewing your answer and comparing it with my previous version I found it actually has the same effect.